# Is Destructo Disk one of the most powerful moves?

Tags: dragon-ball

Destructo Disk is a move created by Krillin that more or less slices through everything (it even cut Frieza's tail). Is it one of the most powerful moves throughout the Dragonball Universe?

Also if we keep moves like the Spirit Bomb that takes its strength from other people instead of just its creator, out of argument is it the most powerful move in the Dragonball Universe? (Any special move that a Super Saiyan God can do is considered not created by a single person since a Super Saiyan God is created by the collaboration of many people.)

By powerful I am only considering how much damage it can do if it hits the target. The fact that it cannot be controlled or it takes too long to be created are not part of the argument.

Comment: the most powerful move is the mystical dragon punch that goku uses on king piccolo. 1 shot kill every time. also i thought that freeza's distructo disc was different then krillins? as krillins sucks and is worthless, but freeza's is extremely dangerous and, i think Cell even says its freeza's distructo disc that he was using on goku in their fight, because according to the manga i dont believe he even has krillins Cells in him.

Comment: You mean this one?
http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Penetrate!

Comment: this one http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Fist  which is the same one afaik but the wiki splits them up.

Comment: @Himarm the one you are referring is much much different. It was never used on King piccolo. It's similar but different

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately Dragonball is filled with hyperboles showing how "powerful" an attack is and it really depends on what you mean by the most powerful moves.

One instance is how Cell said he gathered enough energy to destroy the solar system.

http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Solar_Kamehameha

> "Forget the Earth, I can destroy the entire Solar System with my
>   energy now!"
>
> First, Super Perfect Cell stores up a huge amount of energy as he
>   prepares a Super Kamehameha. He then brings his hands forward and
>   fires a blast that has enough power to wipe out an entire Solar
>   System.

Essentially yes Destructo Disk is pretty powerful because it can cut through anything but that pales in comparison to the power of others in the Dragonball Universe that supposedly have planet busting / galaxy busting / universe busting moves.

In fact other characters have improved versions of Krillin's Signature attack such as Frieza's Death Saucer because it can actually follow a target.

http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Destructo_Disk

> Death Saucer is an improved version of the Destructo Disk created by
>   Frieza and which has the ability to follow a certain target around.
>   Cell can use both versions; Krillin as well as everyone else are
>   shocked when Cell unveils this technique, and Krillin even questions
>   whether Cell improved the attack.

Also note according to the wikia The Destructo Disk doesn't always work.

> Unlike energy blasts, the Destructo Disk can actually injure enemies
>   many times the wielder's power level, such as being able to cut off
>   Frieza's tail when energy blasts from the likes of Vegeta and Gohan
>   proved ineffective. In the anime only, Krillin uses it once on Perfect
>   Cell, with the disk shattering on Cell's neck, being too tough for
>   even Krillin's ki disk's "edge" to cut.

Even though it's not canon Amond deflects Krillin's disk with his own technique as well.

> The Crusher Corps. commander, Amond, uses an unnamed disk-launching
>   technique where he spins on himself before launching a razor-sharp
>   disk of energy. He used this technique to deflect Krillin's Destructo
>   Disk in The Tree of Might.

The overall answer is no Destruco Disk is not the most powerful move in the Dragonball universe because there are attacks that are MUCH more powerful.

Comment: For the improved versions that follow the character or can be controller or etc etc that have nothing to do with what happens when hitting the character is not what matters to me. I only want the attack's results in consideration. 
Now for the power to destroy a solar system. Powers like that (or kamehameha or similar ki attacks) can be blocked,but Destructo Disk must be avoided at all costs because it will cut. You cannot block a Destructo Disk like you can block any other (if you are strong enough) ki attack

Comment: You asked the question is it the most powerful move in Dragonball. The only reason you can't block a Destructo Disk is because it's a razor sharp disk of energy, and in the anime it doesn't actually hurt Perfect Cell.

Answer (score 0):

Destructo Disk is a very minor attack compared to Spirit Bomb; however, an equivalence to the Spirit Bomb exists.

The Sphere of Destruction (seen in Battle of Gods,) created by The God of Destruction, Lord Beerus, can destroy entire planets with ease. All of the power to create this Sphere is coming from one being. Now you could argue that Beerus is The God of Destruction and that he has godly powers, but as mentioned in the film, he acquired the title of God of Destruction and he admitted that one day, he will die of being too old and that someone will replace him. Meaning he CAN die and that he is a mortal being.

Dragonball has god like powers and powerful characters, but in the end, everyone can die.